# Ошибка при попытке передать параметр

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется CRUD и при просмотре статьи имеется кнопка

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['route' => ['purchase', $post->id]]) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Купить', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

При нажатии которой отрабатывает след. метод :

```
 public function purchase($id){

    $post = Posts::find($id);

    $post->amount=$post->amount -1;
    $post->sold_amount=$post->sold_amount +1;
    $post->save();
    $purchase = new Purchase();
    $purchase->post_id = $post->id;
    $purchase->user_id = Auth::user()->id;


    $purchase->save();

    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
}
```

И вместо желаемого результата я получаю ошибку:

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PostController::purchase(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

Подскажите, как исправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По ошибке видно, что не передается параметр `$id`, по конструкции все правильно написано, проверь `$post->id` у тебя точно передается, может быть он пуст.

Comment: Действительно не передаётся, но в чём может быть причина? Вернее передаётся, но через GET и при этом я получаю ошибку  `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message`

Comment: выведите `$post` что там? тут в самой модели `Post` нужно смотреть, может у вас $post не все параметры выводит, где то в `get` указаны конкретные поля и без `id`

Comment: Содержимое `$post` :      `{"id":1,"user_id":2,"title":"rqrq","picture":"1508437358.jpg","price":21,"amount":32,"sold_amount":null,"description":"33213","created_at":"2017-10-19 18:22:38","updated_at":"2017-10-19 18:22:38"} `

Comment: а можешь показать роут `purchase`?

Comment: `Route::post('/purchase', 'PostController@purchase')->name('purchase');`

Comment: посмотри ответ, попробуй в методе `purchase` написать так

Comment: если ругаться на `Request` будет, пропиши на верху `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: Теперь ругается  `ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property of non-object` на     `$post->amount=$post->amount -1`

Comment: странно, не находит объект `$post`, а проверьте `$request->id` теперь нужный приходит? просто получается `Posts::find` не нашел такой записи с таким `id`

Comment: `$request->id` ничего не выводит

Comment: ссори, могу уже сам тупить, роут так пропишите `Route::post('/purchase/{id}', 'PostController@purchase')->name('purchase');` а в `purchase` верните как было

Comment: Премного вам благодарен! Всё окей.